# How to derive this exponential generating function?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Anyone can help to solve this problem?

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the combinatorial class of all functions $f : [1,n] \rightarrow [1,n]$. Derive the exponential generating function and use
it to compute (or verify) the number of such functions.

Answer (score 2):

Going the other way might be easier: the number $|\mathcal{F}(n)|$ is not hard to compute. Consider the function as a vector $(f(1),\ldots,f(n))$, where the coordinates can take the values $[1;n]$. How many such vectors are there?

Once you have this number, you can plug it in to the formula for an exponential generating function.

Comment: Is that f(n)=n! or  f(n)=n^n ?

Comment: But it is actually an interval from point 1 to point n.

Comment: $n^n$ is right. If we're talking about intervals, an exponential generating function would be hard to define. EGFs are only used for finite structures, and functions between intervals are very infinite.

Comment: @ZviRosen It would have to be something related to $T=(xe^{-x})^{\langle -1\rangle}$, something like $1+xT'$.